# How do I show if this system is time-varying?

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems

$\displaystyle y(t) = x(t), t \ge 0$ and $-x(t), t \lt 0$

I can anticipate this system is time-varying.

However, I cannot be sure it and prove it.

please help me.

Comment: Only a *system* can be time-invariant or time-varying, not a *signal*. I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: I have closed this question because you have shown no effort to have us understand where you don't understand.  Have you tried applying the standard test for time invariance? Please apply it as part of your question (i.e. [edit](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/25555/edit) your question) and see if we can point to what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that a system is time-varying, it is sufficient to find one counter-example, where the response to a shifted input signal does not equal a shifted version of the original output signal.

In your case you might want to consider the signal

$$x(t)=\begin{cases}&1,& 0<t<1\\
&-1,& -1<t<0\\
&0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Now try to figure out the corresponding output signal $y(t)$. Next, take a shifted version of $x(t)$, e.g. $x(t-1)$, as the input signal and see what output signal you get. Is it equal to $y(t-1)$? If not, you've just shown that the system is indeed time-varying.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Sorry, you are right. In my text book, question is "determine the following system time-variant or time-invariant"

Comment: I can find out $y(t-1) = 1$ in $1<t<2, -1$ in $0<t<1$, and 0 in otherwise. Although I have to prove $y(t-1)$ is not equal to $S{x(t-1)}$, I don't know $S{x(t-1)}$.

Comment: to me the proposed system seems to be piecewise time-invariant, with the discontinuity at t = 0 splitting the two time-invariant areas.

Comment: @Danny_Kim: First you have to find $y(t)$ for the given $x(t)$. Then you use $x(t-1)$ as an input and see what the system's response is. It may help to sketch the signals.